# Asyncio RuntimeError: Event loop is closed flask app

Tags: python-3.6, gunicorn, python-asyncio

I have a flask app hosted on gunicorn webserver and trying to parallelize long running I/O bound task "somemethod" as shown below. However often times (not always) it throws error "Event loop is closed". What could be the reason for the error happening randomly ?

Removing loop.close() does the fix the errors, but I am not sure if there would be memory leak in the python worker process.

```
async def somemethod():
    """ Do some work """


app.route('/hello', method=['POST'])
def sayhello():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   try:
          asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
          future = asyncio.ensure_future(somemethod)
          loop.run_until_complete(future)
    finally:
          loop.close()
```

Comment: Try to use asyncio.run - https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run 
`asyncio.run(somemethod())` so no need to init loop and close it.

Or remove line with ensure_future  and change line with run_until_complete to `loop.run_until_complete(somemethod())`

In general it's better to use async framework instead of mixing async to Flask, take a look on Sanic, it's similar to Flask

Comment: I am also getting same error. This is happening randomly and is hapening only when I am running the application using gunicorn. If running using only django server then it's working fine.